# Airflow task with trigger_rule none_failed doesn't get skipped correctly

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler, airflow

At the end of my workflow I'm trying to implement 2 tasks in parallel with different trigger rules to log whether the execution of certain tasks was succesful or not. For this I've created 2 tasks with the trigger rules 'one failed' and 'none_failed'. The one failed task gets skipped in case no previous tasks have failed. But in the case of a failure in the parent tasks the none failed task isn't skipped but instead gets an upstream failed even though this shouldn't be the case if I understand the documentation correctly.

Visualisations of the DAG runs:

[task with one_failed TR correctly being skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoSsL.png)

[task with none_failed TR getting the status upstream_failed instead of skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkVd3.png)

Furthermore if I look into the code behind the [dependencies](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/ti_deps/deps/trigger_rule_dep.py) it seems that the code is implemented to behave like this:

```
if flag_upstream_failed:
        if tr == TR.ALL_SUCCESS:
            if upstream_failed or failed:
                ti.set_state(State.UPSTREAM_FAILED, session)
            elif skipped:
                ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
        elif tr == TR.ALL_FAILED:
            if successes or skipped:
                ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
        elif tr == TR.ONE_SUCCESS:
            if upstream_done and not successes:
                ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
        elif tr == TR.ONE_FAILED:
            if upstream_done and not (failed or upstream_failed):
                ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
        elif tr == TR.NONE_FAILED:
            if upstream_failed or failed:
                ti.set_state(State.UPSTREAM_FAILED, session)
            elif skipped == upstream:
                ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
```

But this doesn't seem to mesh with the way the airflow documentation  [describes the none_failed rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=trigger%20rules#trigger-rules)

The operators and dependencies of the test DAG that I'm using, sorry if it seems unnecessarily complex, was trying out some other things as well.

```
firstTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='first',
    bash_command='echo first'
)

secondTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='second',
    bash_command='echo second'
)

thirdTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='third',
    bash_command='echo third'
)

fifthTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='fifth',
    bash_command='echog fifth'
)

sixthTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='sixth',
    bash_command='echo sixth'
)

seventhTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='seventh',
    trigger_rule='one_failed',
    bash_command='echo seventh'
)

eightTask = BashOperator(
    task_id='eight',
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    bash_command='echo eight'
)

firstDummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='firstDummy'
)

secondDummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='secondDummy'
)

thirdDummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='thirdDummy'
)

firstTask >> secondTask
firstTask >> thirdTask
secondTask >> firstDummy
thirdTask >> firstDummy
fifthTask >> secondDummy
sixthTask >> secondDummy
firstDummy >> seventhTask
secondDummy >> seventhTask
firstDummy >> eightTask
secondDummy >> eightTask
eightTask >> thirdDummy
seventhTask >> thirdDummy
```

Comment: Can you post your example DAGs code for us? The visualizations help understand your question and prove your problem, but your code is the source of truth here.

Comment: Hey Zack, edited the post with the basic code of the DAG as well.